# AppleScript is cool. Can I do the same thing in plain Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, applescript

so I'm working on my little Mac app, and I want control Adium with it. AppleScript is very cool:

```
tell application "Adium"
    go away with message "Zoned in for Maths."
end tell
```

*(If you're wondering what this is supposed to be. In order to actually start studying I need to create application that will change my IM status, of course ... )*

I tried it in Script Editor, it worked, and I'm pretty sure that calling AppleScript from Cocoa application is gonna be trivial.

But.

Is AppleScript the only way? I don't mind using AppleScript, but it looks like programming for noobs.

Is there any way to do the same thing as above code does without AppleScript, in plain Objective-C somehow?

Would someone point me to relevant documentation? I tried Google but it was like I don't even know what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interprocess communication in Mac OS X is done by something called Apple Events. AppleScript is one way to send and receive Apple Events to other applications.

Therefore, you just need to construct Apple Events directly and send it to the other app, from Objective-C or whatever other language.

Honestly, if you just want to change the status of Adium, it's easiest to use [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and pass what you just wrote, from inside Objective-C.

If you want to do more complicated stuff, [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the way to go. This mechanism maps Apple Events' object hierarchy to Objective-C's object hierarchy.

If you think that's still a newbie's way, you should directly create Apple Events via [`NSAppleEventDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleEventDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAppleEventDescriptor).

Well, some of us old timers think using Objective-C is a sissy's way. If you think so, you should directly deal with C structs called `AEDesc` and such. See [Apple Events programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/intro_aepg/intro_aepg.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001449) and [the corresponding reference](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000134).

However, I think people who use OS X are all noobs. Real people use Linux.

My dad would say people who use GUI are just too spoiled.

The point is, you don't have to care whether it is a newbie's way or not. The important thing is whether you can achieve what you want. In fact, AppleScript is a very powerful, dynamical language, whose power is not well appreciated by many people. Read [AppleScript language guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) and be surprised.

Comment: That's one amazing answer. I'm not exactly this hacker-wannabe who's ashamed of using GUI. Maybe I made it sound like that. Actually, the reason why I didn't want to use AppleScript is because it hides things that I'm interested in. It hides how it works inside and that's what I'm very curious about. Thanks for the links, I think this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: AppleScript is in fact a very, very powerful language. It's just that most people don't notice. Read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html .

Comment: Yeah, it's "Script" that kind of scares me. I've done lots of Ruby on Rails development, and what makes me super excited about ObjC is that it compiles! Unlike Ruby, where everything that I do inside my program takes looong time during execution. And that's one of the reasons why I'm trying to do everything in ObjC. By the way, do you really use Linux? :-)

Comment: AppleScript is compiled down to byte codes. Do you know how AppleScript Editor do the syntax coloring? It first compiles it, and then it de-compiles the resulting byte code, and then the syntax coloring is trivial.  In any case, most of the time is spent by the heavy machinery of the inter-process communication when you drive other apps. I don't think the choice of programming language matters here.

Comment: Also, don't be excited that ObjC is a compiled language... that shows how young you are. Methods are dispatched at run time in Objective-C, in contrast to C++ where it's mostly determined at the compile time. So Objective-C was thought of as a slow, scripting-like language!

Comment: I actually wouldn't recommend Scripting Bridge at this point. Scripting Bridge requires app developers to design their apps in a certain way that is not Applscript-saavy. I'm finding a lot of apps just won't work with it. It's just too immature to do anything more than tinker with at best, and even then it's a hassle.

Comment: Everyone should trust @Philip ... I don't really use AppleScript in full. How do you think of ObjC-AppScript http://appscript.sourceforge.net/objc-appscript/index.html ?

Comment: I'm still on the fence about ObjC-Appscript, actually. It certainly has traction (more so than SB) and it looks like it could be useful in resolving some of Applescript's inherent issues. But getting it set up—specifically compiling the framework on Snow Leopard—steps out of my particular bounds of knowledge so I'm having nothing but problems so far, though I think the same would be said for most anyone who uses Applescript as their primary language.

Comment: Thanks for the info. One thing which worries me is that Apple categorized the descriptions of Apple Events themselves as "legacy", but keeping Scripting Bridge and Cocoa's "Apple Event support" as current. There seems to be a correspondence between what can be done by SB and what's supported by Cocoa's sdef support. It might happen that Apple keeps SB and Cocoa's sdef support, replacing the underlying Apple Events model with direct Objective-C communications. That would be a big trouble for those who really uses AppleScript to automate non-Cocoa apps, though.

Comment: There is a correspondence between SB and sdef since the header files for SB come from the sdef. But I think the SB framework itself somehow gets in the way because commands that work perfectly in AS don't work in SB (and I recently posted a question related to that). I get the impression that Apple no longer has a clear strategy for Applescript and things are in a state of flux right now.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way would be to use [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] 
    initWithSource:@"tell application \"Adium\" to go away with message \"Zoned in for Maths.\""
];
```

For a more powerful way of accessing scripting, use [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html). Scripting Bridge requires at least the 10.5 SDK. You first need to prepare your app.

1. Use the `sdef` and `sdp` command line utilities to generating header files for the applications you wish to control (see "[Preparing to Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-DontLinkElementID_11)" for details).
2. Add the generated header to your project.
3. Add the ScriptingBridge framework to your project. After that, you can use Objective-C calls to control the other application.

After that, you can use Objective-C to send scripting commands to the application.

```
AdiumApplication *adium = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.adiumX.adiumX"];
for (AdiumAccount* acct in [adium accounts]) {
    [acct goAwayWithMessage:(AdiumRichText *)@"Zoned in for Maths."];
}
```

Status messages are Adium's rich text type (which is `NSTextStorage` under the hood), but it's convertable from plain text, so passing an `NSString` rather than a true `AdiumRichText` should work fine.

There are a few hoops to jump through. For example, you can't [create scripting objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-SW11) in the target application by using its ObjC classes directly; you must use [`classForScriptingClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SBApplication_Class/SBApplication/SBApplication.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SBApplication/classForScriptingClass%3a) to get the class, which you can then use to create objects as normal (i.e. `alloc` and `init`, [`initWithProperties`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SBObject_Class/SBObject/SBObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SBObject/initWithProperties%3a) &c.).

```
// creating an AdiumContactGroup
NSDictionary *props = [NSDictionary 
    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"mathies",@"name",
        nil
];
AdiumContactGroup *mathies= [[[[adium classForScriptingClass:@"contact group"] alloc] 
                              initWithProperties:props]
                             autorelease];
if (mathies) {
    [[adium contactGroups] addObject:mathies];
}
```

Note that other languages (such as Python and Ruby) also have Scripting bindings.

Comment: +1 for noting the hoops that Scripting Bridge has. The show-stopping problem of Scripting Bridge comes in `[[adium contactGroups] addObject:mathies];`: If an application doesn't have a *public container* (`SBElementArray`) in which to place the newly created object, *you can't use it*. All truly useful functionality comes with there being a public container. A lot of applications are not built this way (Adobe Photoshop, which I script regularly, comes to mind here), and runs completely against how Applescript works in its native form.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned sending full Applescript or using the Scripting Bridge.  A third choice is to use [Appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) which is also available for Python and Ruby.  It is a little cleaner (IMO) than using the Scripting Bridge in some ways.  And definitely easier.  Although in other ways Scripting Bridge is better.  It also has the advantage of an application called ASTranslate which will translate most Applescript calls into Appscript.  Here's the Appscript for your little Applescript example.

```
ADApplication *adium = [ADApplication applicationWithName: @"Adium"];
ADGoAwayCommand *cmd = [[adium goAway] withMessage: @"Zoned in for Maths."];
id result = [cmd send];
```

Comment: Just a note since I saw something in the other comments.  There's an XCode project that comes with Appscript.  Just select your OS, build, and then copy Appscript.framework to ~/Library/Frameworks.